# How to make link open in new tab or window in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I haven't found anything that has worked.  I've tried all of the following, to no avail:

- added the attribute `target="_blank"` to the `<a>`
- added `target="someName"` to the `<a>`
- URL starts with `'/'`
- URL starts with `Meteor.absoluteUrl()`
- URL starts with `Meteor.absoluteUrl()` with the `"http://"` removed
- URL as string literal, not returned from template helper
- `<a>` inside `{{#constant}}` region in template
- `<a>` not inside `{{#constant}}` region in template
- `<a>` in the body outside of any template at all
- `<a>` appended to the body in the browser console
- `window.open([url],[target])` with all the aforementioned combinations.

In all cases, the link opens in the same tab as where it was clicked, except for the URLs that didn't start with `http://`, which opened an `about:blank` page in a new tab.

Any idea what's causing this, or how to solve it?

Comment: Meteor was designed for single page web apps, which could explain this. Regardless, I'd say this behaviour is surprising

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems like a bug. I think Meteor should ignore links with `target="_blank"`. Maybe you could create an issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/new)

That said, I have successfully done this as a work around:

*test.html*

```
<template name="test">
  <a href="/new-window" target="_blank">Open new window</a>
</template>
```

*test.js*

```
Template.test.events({
  'click a[target=_blank]': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open(event.target.href, '_blank');
  }
});
```

Also, I have found that adding `http://` works for external links E.g.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank">Open new window</a>
```

I'm not sure why these things didn't work for you. I have only tested them in Chrome, however, so maybe this is a browser issue.

Comment: That worked, thank you!  I hadn't thought of doing it that way.  Works in chrome and firefox so far, haven't tested in other browsers yet.

Comment: While you may want an event handler for a button click, it's pointless for an `a href` element. Like any HTML page, these links are handled by the browser--you don't need to write any code.

Answer (score 0):

if using phonegap. answer is here
[phonegap open link in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser)

Comment: I think you must be missing http from the url. Create a public repo which reproduces the problem and I'd be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not missing the http. Note that this happens when I package my meteor app for iOS. So, you're suggesting I create a proof-of-concept for you to compile an iOS app from?

Comment: oh you didn't mention that. does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

I'm for sure too late for the party, but for those who will end up here trying to find a solution to this problem (like me) I just want to make explicit something about the `window.open([url],[target])` approach mentioned, for those who need a need window instead a new tab..

The third parameter for `window.open` is a list of comma separated specifications. The default value for the second parameter is `_blank` which will make the new window to be opened in a new tab.

`window.open(event.target.href, "", "width=200, height=200");` should open the target URL in a **new window** (not a new tab) with the given dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

create this global helper

```
Helpers.addHttp = function (url) {
  if (!/^(f|ht)tps?:\/\//i.test (url)) {
    url = "http://" + url;
  }
  return url;
}
```

using it in a template

```
<a href="{{addHttp url}}" target="_blank">some text</a>
```

Comment: unfortunately not all websites with SSL (https/ftps) can be also be accessed without it (http).  Additionally you're routing ftps links to http.

Comment: No reasonable person would use addHttp for FTP links. You should create additional helpers like `addHttps` and `addFtp`