# PhoneGap: open link outside the phonegap app

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

i am trying to have a link in my PhoneGap app, that when a user click/touch the link a page is being open in the user's browser (doesn't matter which one) as long as it opens outside the phone gap app.

I tried this:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="openUrlInBlankBrowser();" target="_system"  >LINK</a>
```

Doesn't work :( what am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help,
-- Travis

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I hope this works for you.

```
<script>
    function loadPage(url) {
        if (url === 1) {
            window.parent.location ="https://facebook.com/";
        } else {
            window.parent.location =" https://twitter.com/";
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<a style="display:inline-block; text-decoration:none" onclick="loadPage(1)" href="#">
    <img src="images/logo_facebook.png" target="_blank" style="display:inline-block;"/>
</a>
```

OR you can try

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com', '_blank', 'location=no');">
    without location bar
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew but i tried both and i keep geting the page open INSIDE the app. How do i get it open in the ios browser (safari or wahtever) ?

Comment: @Travis umesh was the one that answered your question, I simply edited his answer to make what he was saying clearer. I posted that this was a possible duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser. Have you checked out the link I posted earlier yet?

Comment: Yes i did. This is what is get: 

This open the page INSIDE the APP:
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_parent',
location=no');">LINK</a>

Comment: And This dosen't really do nything ... :(         <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com', '_system');">LINK</a>