# PhoneGap l Link to System's Browser iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

i don't know Cordova. I am trying to active a user experience where a link INSIDE a phonegap 
onClick open on the user's system's browser -- outside the app -- i tried all this NOT working:

```
    <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');">LINK1</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system' 'location=yes');">LINK2</a>

    <a href="#" onclick="window.open(encodeURI('http://www.google.com'), '_system', 'location=yes');">LINK3</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open(encodeURI('http://www.google.com'), '_system', 'location=no');">LINK4</a>
```

All these are openeing the link INSIDE the app...

l also added : plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" -  in the config.xml

How do i launch a link in an outside browser?

Comment: Please stop asking the same question, it's already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser. If somethings changed and your last question isn't actually a duplicate, then edit it to make it clearer, don't make a new question.

Comment: I actually have the same problem and NONE of the provided answers in the linked question could help me solve this.