# Cordova 3.1 open link in Safari on iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, mobile-safari

I'm building a iOS app with Cordova 3.1. I have a link I would like to open in Safari. I've installed the org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser plugin and it worked well on my iPhone (iOS 7) and on the simulator (iOS5;iOS6.1;iOS7) but if I try (iOS6) on all devices it doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to fix this or tried it on a real device running iOS6?
I'm using this code to open the link:

```
window.open('http://www.google.nl', '_system');
```

Comment: Did you already take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser)?

Comment: Yes, I tried all methods I could found on Google.

Comment: What happens if you open your link from an hardcoded `<a>` HTML tag?

Answer (score 3):

well I've implemented this through native side (Objective C)

Add this method in 'MainViewController.m'

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSString *str = url.absoluteString;
    NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"http://"];
    NSRange range1 = [str rangeOfString:@"https://"];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound || range1.location != NSNotFound) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
}
```

This take cares of both 'http' and 'https' link for both iOS6 & iOS7, and opens the link in default browser of the device.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've encountered it too and just written a small plugin to help with it. Siddhartha's answer is almost right, but when I used it, it intercepted all web requests, including those to my `index.html`, and this seemed to move my app into Safari. What I needed was a way to handle only explicit requests, so I could open specific (external) URLs in Safari.

There are many similar questions about Phonegap, which appears to embed special handling for `window.open` with `_system`. That would be nice, but Cordova doesn't have this functionality.

In the end, I wrote a [small plugin](https://github.com/morungos/cordova-plugin-ios-safari) that embeds enough Objective C (closely modelled on Siddhartha's answer) but due to the magic of plugins, it can be executed on demand, using `cordova.exec`. I'd love this to patch into window.open to achieve the same functionality as Phonegap, but that'll be for another day, and it doesn't really affect this answer.

As far as I can tell, in modernish Cordova, this is the only viable strategy.