# Phonegap App Won't Open External Link

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

**Issue Solved. TIL i need to add a script link to Cordova in my html**

I know the event is firing as my server shows the request to the link when I click on the button. It connects fine with chrome on my pc and tablet but the native app button won't open the system browser for me.

The link connects to a .apk download which the server is registering as requested when I press the button so the event handling is not the issue afaik. I've also tried '_blank' instead of system but still no joy

Any help would be much appreciated

Edit: Also tried `navigator.app.loadUrl` as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser)

Edit Edit: Hmmmm, I tried inserting an ´alert("test");´ statement in the first line of the function and that's not firing... yet server of the target link is registering the requests.

The relevant patch of code is here:

```
Server.getUpdateInfo(getDevice()?getDevice():"Android", function (data) {
        if(data.IsUpdate){
            if(getDevice()){
                $("#btnInstall").on("click", function(){
                    window.open($(this).data("url"),'_system');
                });
            }
            else {
                    $("#btnInstall").closest(".ui-btn").hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        id        = "com.blahblahblah"
        version   = "1.0.4">
    <name>Server App</name>

    <description>
        jQuery Mobile interface for Server Admin
    </description>

    <author>
        Firma GmbH
    </author>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
    <preference name="orientation"      value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />



    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />

</widget>
```

Comment: Use inAppBrowser to open a link in browser

Comment: @NijilNair "I've also tried '_blank' instead of system but still no joy"

Comment: You should add answer to your own question and accept it so the question gets closed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure there's a link to the cordova script in your html file. No need to load the file yourself as phonegapp will build it.