# Viewing a PDF file from HTML5 Hybrid Mobile App

Tags: android, html, cordova

Intending to view a PDF File from the Hybrid Mobile App , created using HTML5 Jquery and Packaged with Phonegap.

But unable to achieve it ,

Things i tried

```
<object src="xyz.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

also,

```
 window.open('xyz.pdf'); //through javascript
```

and

```
$(document).load('xyz.pdf');
```

Can anyone suggest the best way for viewing the PDF in a Hybrid Android Mobile App.

Comment: possible duplicate of [phonegap open link in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser)

Answer (score 2):

with cordova you must think about these:

**HTML 5 object tag**: not working

If you try with:

```
 window.open('http://www.???.com/my.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

The InAppViewer can´t open this kind of files.

I think that there aren't an hybrid solution for this problem.
You must start to search or write about a plugin that use a native pdf's opening and then use it.
An example:

[cordova-plugin-file-opener](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2)

The latest solution, a little more simple but include to open google docs is:

```
window.open('https://docs.google.com/viewer? url=http://www.example.com/test.pdf&embedded=true', '_blank', 'location=yes'); 
ref = window.open('index.html', '_self');
```

Comment: Hi @phemt.latd , i am getting an error , unable to read the property of undefined : fileopener , when i am trying to access the cordova-plugin-file-opener , how can that be fixed ... I have used the .java and .js file of that plugin and configured that in config.xml of my project.

Comment: try to reset the plugin and install it with this command: **cordova plugin add https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2** if you install it by cordova-cli all the configuration is managed by cordova.

Comment: I used the Google docs solution, it's the only one that worked for me ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Go look at the Mozilla [pdfJS project](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

This project allows you to open a pdf (embedded in app or remote) in your app. No break-out links that relies on native viewers.

They also give you a very full featured sample viewer, that you can use as is, but much of functionality in that does not apply to mobile applications.

I have had success with this on Android 4.3 Devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the InAppBrowser plugin to do so. I have use it to open PDF files right inside the app on both iOS and Android.

Check the official [InAppBrowser doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) with full doc and examples, it has several options you can enable/disable (be sure to point to your current cordova version documentation):

Answer (score 0):

My solution for connected apps with offline availability...

```
window.open('http://www.someserver.com/doc.pdf', '_system')
```

...this will open in default pdf viewer.  I have my clients use adobe reader for obvious reasons.  And also because once it is downloaded the first time, adobe app manages and edits the documents well, and the documents are also available offline from within adobe reader thereafter. Even pdf forms.

Have cordova.js linked on the page.
Have inAppBrowser added.

For full offline you may try FileOpener plugin.  I have not needed to do that on android, but I have used that way in iOS.

Hope any of this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Though am late here, still want to share what I know. [You can use this plugin](https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer) to view PDFs in the app (without inappbrowser). Supports only Android and iOS.