# Opening a link in web browser

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

Yes so many workarounds I found over Net, thank Google. None of them worked! I'm gonna list them here:

1- Using `data-rel` attribute, setting value to `external`

2- Installing cordova `InAppBrowser` plugin as well as adding `onclick` attribute `onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system'); return false;"` to the respective `a` tag

3- Checking whether or not `cordova.js`, `cordova_plugins.js` are existed & included in relevant html file

They were the most suggested ideas I found on Stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser) and the other forums. Yet it's opened within app window!

I appreciate your help.

Comment: try removing jquery mobile, if it works at least you know it's a jquery mobile problem, if it does't work, then might be a problem installing the plugin

Answer (score 1):

Using `phonegap` without jquery-mobile and having the `InAppBrowser` plugin installed I can view a link using:

```
window.open(encodeURI('https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=jxvBVKuLIOqD0AXI74CACQ#q=woop'), '_system', 'location=yes');
```

If you are trying to open a link of a .pdf file it will download it to the device.
Hope that helps.