# Open a link in device browser window from iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

In Ionic project, I had loaded my Responsive Website URL in an iFrame and it looks fine. But there are few anchor links in my website which will open a new window, for eg :

```html
<a href="http://mydevice.io/devices/" target="_blank"> Devices List </a>
```

This is working fine for Desktop browsers, but the same is not opening any new window or not even opening in default browser. Am seeing this problem only with iFrame. I tried with Different targets and also used InAppBrowser, no progress.

Comment: have you already seen and tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser ? perhaps it needs to be adapted to your case

Comment: @beaver beaver, Yeah I had checked that. That issue is outside the iFrame which I know already. But this problem is opening a new window from inside the iFrame content

Answer (score 0):

Might be of help to someone blocked due to this

`<a href="#" onclick="parent.window.open('http://mydevice.io/devices/', '_system', );">Devices List</a>`

This will get reference to parent container window object and will work as expected.