# Can't open downloaded video with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I download my files with:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(
  url,
  target,
  ..
);
```

And then i open them later with:

```
window.open(targetUrl, '_blank', 'location=no');
```

It works for PDF, XLX, DOCX etc. but not for AVI or MP4. 
It opens the Video Player with a Play Button and a 'loading..' Text.
If i try to open the AVI or MP4 directly it plays the files just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Edit: I use a iPad
Edit2: **The Error: webView:didFailLoadWithError - 204: Plug-in handled load**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question:

Streaming of Videos in the browser is supported and playing local files is not. A native plugin will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this if you have HTML:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Try something like this is you just have Javascript:

```
function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {
    var source = document.createElement('source');

    source.src = src;
    source.type = type;

    element.appendChild(source);
}

var video = document.createElement('video');

document.body.appendChild(video);

addSourceToVideo(video, targetUrl, 'video/mp4');

video.play();
```

Also, ensure that you have the inappbrowser plugin installed.

```
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

per: [phonegap open link in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser)

Comment: I have no html. How do i start the video from javascript?

Comment: Thanks. I`ll try that. But i really want to know why the normal way just wont work.