# jquery - force to open web in built-in default web browser on mobile device

Tags: jquery, mobile, browser, native

## the context

We are on mobile device and chatting on an app e.g. Facebook Messenger.
Our website is opened via a pasted URL in the chat window.

And we are in our jquery code.

## the need

We need a way to open an URL in system built-in web browser - i.e. one situation is to get rid of Facebook in-app browser.

So how can we force opening an URL using the native browser on the device?

Comment: Where is your code running right now? In a non-built-in browser?

Comment: I have update `the context`. My code is normal website jquery code. The web opened from a mobile app and that app uses its own browser.

Comment: You probably may have alread tried [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser)? – blackpen

Comment: OMG ^^ Yes I found when google search for this topic. Your 2nd suggestion is on PhoneGap only i.e. `window.open('url', '_system')` only works for PhoneGap

Comment: I don't have windows mobile. What is the name of your system browser? Is it Microsoft Edge by any chance?

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304466.aspx) if using VBScript may help you.

Comment: Oh I really looking for jquery that compatible among browsers/devices. Thanks a lot anyway!