# Ionic InAppBrowser with PayPal link

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have implemented a PayPal button with InAppBrowser, user goes to PayPal account to donate after clicking and it works as it should but unfortunately our App got rejected by Apple. Their reasoning was that PayPal or donation links should be outside the App. Even thought I have no control over InAppBrowser it is still considered as part of the App.
Weirdly I could not find something related to this, I was hopping for it to be very common.

Also tried window.open with different arguments while removing InAppBrowser and nothing happened.

I know that prompting the User to pick a browser will solve the issue but somehow that is not working for me! I remember getting around it on the past but I do not remember the solution(probably different Cordova plugin). Any suggestion how to solve it? Any other approach is welcomed.

Thank you guys!

Comment: the problem is apple, not your code. i know it's offtopic, but apple want's that you sell your app over their app-store because they want to earn money. if you use a donate via paypal, they won't earn anything. in my eyes, apple has to be composted for some actions they do.

Comment: @TypedSource We have InAppPurchase and Ads so Apple can still get something there

Comment: @HerbiShitini we had this discussion with apple germany half a year ago and had to remove the donate link after 4 hours of discussion for acception of the app. they simply don't want it and it looks that they are browsing every app by hand before accepting. but this all is stuff for a forum. please close the question.

Comment: @TypedSource well we sent them a message and they made it clear that prompting User to pick a browser out of the app will make it pass the test. In fact it makes sense because User is not secure when entering sensitive data inside the Webview

Comment: perhaps you find what you want in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser

Comment: @TypedSource this is embarrassing. I was pretty sure I tried "_system" but somehow I should have had something wrong. It worked, Thank you!