# How can I open a url in web browser not my app?

Tags: javascript, browser, phonegap

with phonegap I develope web based applicaton using html and javascript.In my app there is URL but when user click that url work in my app
I want to open that url in web browser what should I do?

Comment: What do you have tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phonegap open link in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887348/phonegap-open-link-in-browser)

Comment: @Amanjaura Window.open() but this call work inside application I want to work in web browser not my ap

Comment: Have a look at the above link suggested by @AndrewLohr. It might solve your problem.

Comment: @AndrewLohr do you suggest inappbrowser?I will try this but I will use webview.One page only.That page is just webview.So using that plugin is enough?I can handle page -url which will loaded to my webview